# Getting an InfoPath form to auto populate when a drop down is selected.

Tags: sharepoint, autocomplete, infopath

I've followed [this blog][1]

[1]: https://blogs.technet.microsoft.com/anneste/2011/11/02/how-to-create-an-infopath-form-to-auto-populate-data-in-sharepoint-2010/ which works like a dream.

It populates an email field with my email address but what I what to happen is that a user selects someone using a people picket field and then fields are populated with that persons details.

Any idea how I could achieve this? Thanks

Answer (score 0):

Before the infopath rule: "Query for Data: GetUserProfileByName"
You have to populate the query field "Account Name" of the GetUserProfileByName data connection with the account name you selected in the peoplepicker field.

Comment: Cheers, so how would I change that? If I go via the Data tab/Data Connections then Modify I don't get the option to change the query field?

Comment: Sorry, I think I got the wrong end of the stick. It's setting the Condition isn't it?  So now I've got 'Person' > 'Is Blank' is that correct?

Comment: You have to set a rule for example on the people picker field, in that rule you can set field value, choose for the data connection of the GetUserProfileByName and select the field from the query field.

Comment: Cheers. I managed to get to that point and now I'm trying to put a formula in to return the values, I've put 'Values[Name = "FieldProfileName"]' but it's returning the error "Values/Name does not point to a valid location path of a field or group." ?